# mongoose aggregate model based on filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a model of `Review` which has the field `product` and `rating`

I would like to find the sum of all ratings of a specified product and find the average by dividing by 5.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ReviewSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  product: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product',
    required: true,
  },
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Review', ReviewSchema);
```

how would I aggregate through all ratings and filter by product to find the sum?

Comment: can you provide the schema of  Product

Comment: share sample documents

Comment: I just want to filter by the id for the product, the product model just has fields like name, price, merchant, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your using nodejs , here is how I would go about doing this

```
const ReviewsModel = require('../Models/Review')
router.get('/average',async (req,res)=>{ 
    try {
        const reviewsPromise = await ReviewsModel.find({}).populate('product')
        if(reviewsPromise[0] == undefined) throw new Error('no reviews')

        const reviewsOfSpecifiedProduct= reviewsPromise.filter(rev=> rev.product.id == specifiedProductId)
        const sumOfRatings =  reviewsOfSpecifiedProduct
                               .map(rev=>rev.rating)//map to list of only ratings 
                               .reduce((a, b)=> a + b , 0)
        const ratingsAverage = sumOfRatings / 5 
        

        res.json(ratingsAverage)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        //handle the errors here 
    }
})
```

Comment: cool... i'll replace `.find()` to `.find({product: product.id})`

Comment: ohh yeah I forgot that , then you wouldn't need  ```populate('product')``` , but I don't think it'll work because you will be comparing a string to un objectId .

Comment: works fine `const reviews = await Review.find({ product: parent.id });`